# when mounting a host directory -v option. Are the mounts available by the time the ENTRYPOINT starts?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile as follows

```
FROM rajenata/ovs
MAINTAINER Rajesh Nataraja <...>
COPY initovs /sbin/

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/initovs"]
CMD ["--help"
```

Then I execute

```
docker run -d rajenata/ovs:2 --net=host --privileged -v /etc/openvswitch:/etc/openvswitch
```

But the initovs script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "/etc/openvswitch" ]; then
  if [ -f "/etc/openvswitch/conf.db" ]; then
     echo "DB Exists No Need to Create"
  else
     ovsdb-tool create  /etc/openvswitch/conf.db /usr/local/share/openvswitch/vswitch.ovsschema
  fi
else
  echo "Open V Switch not mounted from Host"
  exit -1
fi
```

Returns an `exit -1` indicating the mount is not available.

Is it possible that the `ENTRYPOINT` executes even before `DOCKER` completes the mount?

Comment: Docker mounts are available when `ENTRYPOINT` runs.  Other than the exit code, is there any error output that indicates what the problem is?  Can you post that output in your question?

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing you are running this with a normal user. You might not have access to /etc/openvswitch (even though the user is part of docker group). Ideally, mounts are available before the `ENTRYPOINT`. Even if you create a script echoing only "hello world" and mount that at some location in container and run it on entrypoint, it does print "hello world". So, mostly to me it seems to be permission issue. You can login to container and see if that file is there or not.

```
$ docker run -it rajenata/ovs:2 --net=host --privileged -v /etc/openvswitch:/etc/openvswitch /bin/bash
container-name# ls /etc/openvswitch
```

Try to see what error you are getting if you try to perform the same operation as you were performing in the entrypoint.

Comment: core@... ~/ovs-docker $ sudo docker run -d rajenata/ovs:2 --net=host --privileged -v /etc/openvswitch:/etc/openvswitch
d0eade3e58525cdcc18b2a17116dd442decae7c3edb57cbdd259606ed0af55af

core@... ~/ovs-docker $ docker logs d0eade3e5852
Open V Switch not mounted from Host
core@... ~/ovs-docker $

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue does not seem to appear after another rebuild of container. Not really sure what went wrong.